# cakephp combining associated array fields

Tags: php, cakephp, multidimensional-array, cakephp-2.1

I've an associated array with 20 elements whose child array looks like

```
(int) 2 => array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'user_id' => '13',
        'time' => '2012-05-18 14:47:36'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'name' => 'User name'
    )
)
```

Now I want to extract the field *name* from its child array *User* with cakephp's [set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html) utility and append it to the child array *Comment*. Is there a one way step to do this other than using a for or foreach loop?

```
(int) 2 => array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'user_id' => '13',
        'time' => '2012-05-18 14:47:36',
        'name =>'User name'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't answer your question, but doing this with a `foreach` is a *one way step* too:

```
foreach ($arrays as $array)
  $array['Comment']['name'] = $array['User']['name'];
```

I believe there's no need to use some utility, just for the sake of using an utility.
Especially that it'll do a `foreach` itself.